# How to export Quick Help Documentation for User Defined Function in Xcode 8 to HTML

Tags: xcode

I know how to add the documentation in Xcode but I am unable to find , how to export that documentation to HTML.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 major apps/command line tools that can do what you want

- [Headerdoc](https://opensource.apple.com/source/headerdoc/)
- [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html)

### Headerdoc

Is an open source documentation to html script/command line tool from Apple, Inc.

Headerdoc is provided by default in all versions of OS X/macOS just open Terminal and use the following to figure out what you have:

> which headerdoc2html

and then read the man page using something like this:

> man headerdoc2html

### Doxygen

Supports many languages and has a few tag/format differences from Headerdoc

---

Which one you will want to use will be based on what language you are using, Headerdoc may not support the language you want and doxygen might not either, your mileage may vary. Read the documentation and supported languages to make your choice. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Do you have a direct link to Headerdoc?

Comment: @AmrElAdawy No, as it's on that Headerdoc page, and because my reputation was too low I couldn't provide more than 2 links

Comment: write the link here and I will update the post for you

Comment: https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/headerdoc/headerdoc-8.9.28.tar.gz but i would think that a direct link isn't preferred, because if apple were to update the file it'd be an old link. Also I forgot to mention (i'll update my answer) Headerdoc is included with all versions of OS X/macOS